# Unable to identify element in IOS

Tags: appium, appium-ios

I have been trying to click the attached highlighted (in red arrow) icon from IOS using Appium but keep getting timeout exception. This click is required against only the record of '193930 Copy 1' in a table. Any assistance?

```
Appium: 1.6.2
XCode: 9.4
Tested in?: Native App
IOS: 11.4
Model: iPhone X
```

Exception:-

> org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for visibility of element located by By.xpath:

Tried Xpaths are:-

```
//XCUIElementTypeStaticText[@name='193930 Copy 1']/XCUIElementTypeButton[contains(@name, 'more')]

(//XCUIElementTypeStaticText[@name='193930 Copy 1'])/following-sibling::XCUIElementTypeButton[@name='more']

//XCUIElementTypeStaticText[@name='193930 Copy 1']/XCUIElementTypeButton[`name == "more"']

//XCUIElementTypeStaticText[contains(@name,'193930 Copy 1')]/following-sibling::XCUIElementTypeButton
```

//XCUIElementTypeStaticText[contains(@name,'193930 Copy 1')]/XCUIElementTypeButton

[image]

Comment: Are there more than one of those "More"-Buttons on the page?

Comment: Yes, Table contains list of records and 'more' button is associated against each record.

Comment: Your last locator looks the most-correct to me.  Add xpath to the tags list in this post so that people who are more experienced with xpath can comment and possibly offer a better solution.  I'd do it for you but it would require peer approval, if you as the original poster do it, it will go right through.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to replicate the problem you have in our own app and this is what I came up with and it worked for me (Please mind that I use Appium version 1.7.1, this could affect the outcome):

```
//XCUIElementTypeStaticText[@name='193930 Copy 1']/following-sibling::XCUIElementTypeButton
```

You don't need to specify the name of the next element, as you can just use the structure of the app. I think what went wrong in your tries is that you combined the wrong attributes.